Emulator not showing on screen but running in background
I shifted my sdk folder and .android folder into D drive from C drive, since then I have been having few issues, first my emulator (Google pixel 7 pro) was not showing in vs code, so I tried all solutions I could find like path changes, something about ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_SDK_HOME, restarting adb server, re-installing vs code etc, but nothing was working, so I made the .android folder back on C drive in its original place and changed the paths accordingly (the sdk is still in D drive), now the google pixel emulator is showing but when I try to run, it opens for a second and disappears. It is running in background but nothing is there on my screen. When I run it in android studio it is running properly.
(Flutter SDK has been in D drive since day 1)


btw It was working fine when everthing was in C drive and I made 2-3 projects following tutorials. What should I do now, do I have to re-install everything in C drive. Please feel free to ask any details I forgot to include.
(Somehow my bluetooth earphones also stopped working in my laptop since this, they are connected but sound is coming from laptop itself I hope they are not related)
